# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity - starting new Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to start a New Activity using Intent but I keep getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity`

What am I doing wrong?

Main Activity

```
package com.example.wrw;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void clicked(View v)
    {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, newact.class);
         startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

newact.java

```
package com.example.wrw;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class newact extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);
    }


}
```

act_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Act" 
        android:onClick="clicked"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

newlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wrw"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you have not added `newact` Activity to your manifest ...

Comment: try Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newact.class) and also register newact in manifest file

Comment: why the question is downvoted ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In android app, all `Activity` must be configured in the `Manifest.xml` file firstly, so you should add `newact Activity` to your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.wrw.newact"></activity>
```

Comment: There is no problem in your Activities but one thing you missed is registering the activity in your manifest file. Normally when ever we are using a new activity that we need to register in manifest file. So that only it will recognize by the
android system calls.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newact.class)
```

and also register `newact` in manifest file like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".newact"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

Comment: same as you registered MainActivity

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".newact"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
         </activity>

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name=".newact"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login">
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this to your **MainActivity**, this may resolve your problem.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newact.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

After this, do not forget to **add this in your android menifest file**,

```
    <activity
        android:name=".newact"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```